# PostgreSQL: How to find out the type of replica without master?

Tags: postgresql, cluster-computing, failover

I have 1 replica host on which the postgres instance is running. I need to understand whether this replica is synchronous or asynchronous. Is there any hack, how can I find out without access to the master?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, because there is no difference on the standby side.

The only difference is if the primary waits for feedback from the standby during `COMMIT` or not.

You will have to examine `synchronous_standby_names` on the primary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using synchronous replication, you would have specified an `application_name` in `recovery.conf`. However, you could set `application name` without using synchronous replication (i.e., `synchronous_standby_names` never got set on master’s conf), but that’s the only hint as to whether you are using synchronous v. asynchronous replication. Otherwise, you need to check from the master side.

Comment: The control system sets application_name for any instance. After adding a synchronous replica through the same control system, its application_name is not added to `synchronous_standby_names` on the master.

Comment: Then in that case you have to determine synchronous usage via master

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if XACT_COMPLETION_APPLY_FEEDBACK is set in the commit records in the WAL files.  I think that that would only work under "remote_apply", though.  Also, there is no easy way to check this.  You would have to manually parse some WAL records, or add code to pg_waldump to print this extra info, or maybe add code to xact_redo_commit in xact.c to log when it sees it.  I don't think there is a way to tell if a level below "remote_apply" is being used.